# $interval happening too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hopefully I can explain this so you can understand. I just finished up a question getting help with angular's `$interval` functionality. Let's start from the basics first:

- I have a dropdown where a user selects an option.
- That action calls a select method which makes a `$http.get( )`
  request.
- The resulting data is then placed into a list using `mg-repeat`.
- The data can be updated from another service, so I need this list to
  periodically poll and refresh the list, enter `$interval`

In this code below, I am close, but not quite there. Say I want to refresh the list once every 10 seconds, if I choose option 1 from the start, it will refresh option 1's list every 10 seconds. Great right?

Now if I choose option 2, in terms that I understand, it seems like it creates another thread. It changes the `$http.get( )` where it goes from option 1 to option 2, but it keeps option 1's `$interval` thread open. So it pings option 2's `$http.get( )` twice in 10 seconds. Once following the time interval of the first request ever(for option 1) and once in the interval of me selecting option 2.

Here is the JS code for the select function. This happens when a user selects something from the dropdown:

```
    $scope.select = function() {
      $scope.searchText = '';
      $scope.selectedItem = null;
      var url = 'http:xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
      url += $scope.selectModel.name;
      console.debug("GOING TO: " + url);
      $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
        });
      });
      $interval(function() {
        $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
        });
      });
    }, 30000);
};
```

And here is the section of html in question:

```
<div style="margin: 1em">
<h4>Search</h4>
        <div role="form">
            <!-- start dropdown -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" ng-options="model as model.name for model in allModels" ng-model="selectModel" ng-change="select()">
                    <option value="">Choose Model</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- /end dropdown-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="start_date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Threat Date">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped" ng-show="records">
            <thead>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </thead>
            <tr data-ng-repeat=" item in records | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="moreInfo(item)">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name.slice(5)}}</td>
                <td>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if i need to clarify some. Thanks.

Comment: I see nothing that will stop the interval once you start it. And, since it's in a function, it's bound to be started multiple times, so... yeah... If you're familiar with setInterval, it works in a very similar way. It continues to run until you stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cancel your interval.

```
// Activate
var myInterval = $interval(....);

// Deactivate
$interval.cancel(myInterval);
myInterval = undefined; // Necessary for conditional checking
```

Comment: Got it to work thanks m8. But could you explain what you mean by the bottom part?

Comment: Set interval keeps going until you tell it to stop. The first interval will still be calling the function, until you do the deactivate steps from Mike's answer.

Comment: @erp The "undefined" part is because a cancelled interval still has a value. If you do any conditional, e.g. if(myInterval), it will still return true. Setting myInterval to undefined allows you to really check that it's been cleared.